# What happens when you remove a token creature from the game, and then return it under it's owner's control?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

1. Player A plays [Roar of the Wurm](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Roar%20of%20the%20Wurm)
2. Player B plays [Astral Slide](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Astral%20Slide)
3. Player B recycles a card and returns the Wurm token

What happens then?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Tokens disappear whenever they leave the battlefield. The relevant rules are:

> **110.5f** A token that's phased out, or that's in a zone other than the battlefield, ceases to exist. This is a state-based action; see rule 704. (Note that if a token changes zones, applicable triggered abilities will trigger before the token ceases to exist.)
>
> **110.5g** A token that has left the battlefield can't move to another zone or come back onto the battlefield. If such a token would change zones, it remains in its current zone instead. It ceases to exist the next time state-based actions are checked; see rule 704.

So the Wurm token would be gone for good in this example.